# How do I set "Upload Image" as detault "Set Featured Image" window?

Tags: post-thumbnails

We have few WordPress sites with custom themes where new posts are added very frequently (more than 200 posts a day) so we are trying to be as efficient as possible. I tried to google for a solution but could not find an answer on this topic.

When the Post author clicks on **Set Featured Image** we want them to directly show them the **Feature image** uploader window since 99% of the time, we have different feature images for each post.

[image: Upload File]

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/391259/edit) to include any code samples you've tried, even if they didn't work. As currently written, this question doesn't fit well in a WordPress development Q&A site.

Comment: @PatJ As I mentioned in my post, I could not find any code sample or any other related discussion while Googling. All the results are about beginner tutorials about "How to set feature image".

Comment: Custom bookmarklets `javascript:!function(){...code that clicks on buttons/links and makes some checks...}();` can sometimes do quick & dirty wonders with e.g. custom shortcut keys browser extensions :-)

Comment: @birgire We have few staffs working remotely. It may work for individuals but not for mid/large scale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WordPress exposes media upload component globally, as well the featured image modal with `wp.media.featuredImage` so developers can interact with it.

FeaturedImage component uses the `wp.media.frame` which is a Backbone component, which has custom event attached to it.

There's not much documentation on it, you can check the [source here](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.7.2/src/js/_enqueues/wp/media/editor.js).

You can use the following snippet to achieve your needs.
It's uses the `open` event on media frame and set's content mode to `upload`, the default mode is `browse`.

```php
function wpse_391259_init_featured_uploader_tab() {
    $script = <<<JSS
    (function (){
        var frame = wp.media.featuredImage.frame();
        frame.on( 'open',function() {
            frame.content.mode('upload')
        });
    })();
JSS;

    wp_add_inline_script( 'media-editor', $script );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_media', 'wpse_391259_init_featured_uploader_tab' );
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It works. This one less click is going to save so much time in the long run. I am surprised this hasn't been discussed that much.